# Javascript var loaded from a php function can't get reload with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, onload

I am looking for answer to this question all over the internet for hours now..

I want this Game (php function) to reload itself every second. so that the information in the php function will be updated automatically and the user will see live info in the minutes it changes/added to the database. 
I tried to do that using ajax and jquery and many method that was suggested online but everytime it throws the error no matter what i'm trying to do:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Game is not defined at window.onload

```
  window.onload = function() {    

  var Game = <?php Print(Game("special_number_here")); ?>;

  //... rest of code .. 

  });
```

I tried functions and method that was offered to other people on stackoverflow and other sites and couldn't find the answer...

THANKS (IM GETTING CRAZY OVER THIS)
** & sorry for my poor grammer **

Comment: so you are asking about this error `Uncaught ReferenceError` or about a way to automatically reloading ?

Comment: Well, both beacuse it connected in my script. the reason i get this Uncaught is because im trying to automatically reloading :) @HassanAhmed

Answer (score 0):

it will repeat your piece of code after every second

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ 
   var Game = <?php Print(Game("special_number_here")); ?>;
   // do stuffs
 }, 
1000);
```

whenever you want to stop it just use `clearInterval(myVar);`

try this

```
var Game = <?php Print(Game("special_number_here")); ?>;

var myVar = setInterval(function(){ 
    Game = <?php Print(Game("special_number_here")); ?>;
       // do stuffs
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hi, still getting the "Uncaught ReferenceError: gameBoard is not defined
    at window.onload " error and it makes the script stop working..

Comment: Ok, i tried the updated one. it does not shows any error now and the script is running, but the Game function is not being updated. maybe i should be clearer about what Game does, its a function getting info from the database and i want to change the var Game whenever the db change so it will be updated to the content in the db.